# In Excel, how do i check if cell contains at least twice the same character from a list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list:

```
"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","K","J","Q","T"
```

Then I have cells:

```
6s 3d 3c     yes (2)
6s 3s 2d     no
6s 3s 2s     no
2s 2d 2c     yes (3)
.....
```

I want to check if the cell A6 (here 6s 3d 3c) contains at least 2 times the same character from the list above and returns yes if there is a pair or a triplet. I use list because i don't want the s to count here.

Any thoughts how to do it? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data in a range, use OR() to iterate replacing each character and see if the string length is different by more than 2.

```
=OR(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,$D$1:$D$13,""))>=2)
```

Depending on one's version this formula may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: genius! thank you!